# 0-9 V DC to -9 to 9 V?

Tags: voltage, power, dc, dc-dc-converter

I have a DC signal going from 0 to 9 V. How can I rescale it to the -9 to 9 V range?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auj4y.jpg)
I have infra red sensor , this sensor is damaged , this sensor generate _9 to +9 DCV , 
This sensor connected the board , 
Now , I buy new infrared sensor , but new sensor generate DC voltage from 0 to 9
I need to convert new signal (0 to 9) to -9 to 9
Mr @MCG suggestions the lmc 766, but this IC convert posetive voltage  to negative     voltage 
      when 
Volt is 9 >I need 9 volt.
Volt is 8>I need 7.  Volt.
Volt is 7>i need 5. Volt.
Volt is 6>i need 3.  Volt.
Volt is 5>I need 1. Volt.
Volt is 4>I need _1. Volt.
Volt is 3>I need _3. Volt.
Volt is 2>I need _5. Volt.
Volt is 1>I need _7. Volt.
Volt is 0>I need _9. Volt.    [image]  [image]

Comment: Calm down. No need to shout!

Comment: How precise do you want ? Does your signal have to drive "heavy" load ?

Comment: no . for 500 MA load

Comment: What ? 500 Mega Amperes ?

Comment: Or 500 mA, charge pump like MCG's suggestion cannot provide that much current.

Comment: 500mili amper, I can not understand MCG idea

Comment: Also, what you have added is not a schematic. It is just showing the signal. I understand what you want with the signal. The question is *why* does the signal need to be -9V to +9V? That will help when it comes to drawing a schematic. Is the *signal* driving a load? Or is it just being used to indicate something? You may need to tell us *what the circuit is* and how it is being used. Please provide more of an explanation if you want more assistance, otherwise we could be providing ideas which are useless for your application

Comment: I need this signal for another board , board connect tothe infrared sensor, now sensor is damaged, although old sensor generate _9to 9, but new sensor generate 0 to +9 , I try connect new sensor to board , detail of sensor is similar, it has a different between two sensor , only scale of voltage

Comment: @LongPham using the LM7660 isn't meant to provide the current. I was using it as a suggestion to get a positive and negative rail, which he can then use to change his signal (probably via some op amp circuitry or the like) which is quite simple, but I have to ask for clarification on what the intention of the circuit is

Comment: @MORSALNorouzy in that case can you please update the *question* with the relevant information. This will make sure people attempting to help don't need to crawl through the comments to find it. Also, please **add a schematic** which will make this a whole lot easier

Comment: You said : . I was using it as a suggestion to get a positive and negative rail, I need this topic , please explain about this idea,

Comment: No, *you* need to explain *your* idea. Again, please put the relevant information in the **question**. No, I will ask one last time, please update the question with a **schematic** and an **explanation** of what you are trying to do, along with any **datasheets** of parts you are using. This is the 3rd and last time I am asking for this information. If the question is not updated properly, or you keep asking for things in the comments, I won't be replying any more as it is going in circles. **YOU** need to clarify what you want if you need further assistance.

Comment: My language is elementry , ok

Comment: Incomprehensable English. VTC as unclear.

Comment: Modified my guestion

Comment: You have modified it and still not provided a schematic which makes your description really hard to follow. As I said, I cannot help anymore untill the things I asked for are done

Comment: I don't have schematic , when signal is analog , I can draw the schematic with operation amplifier, but this signal is DC

Comment: i modified again .please see. and please help me

Comment: It **needs** a schematic in order to understand what you are doing. Your description is unclear. If you can't solve your issue after my solution then clearly something else is going on that needs a visual aid like a schematic. If you don't have one, make one

Comment: Schematic uploaded

Comment: If you're powering your sensor with +/-12V then you shouldn't have any trouble with that you're wanting. And that's not a schematic

Comment: What is it schematic ? Please explain about schematic, that picture explain complete system, DC signal related to postion of subject(textile)

Comment: I don't have any internal circuit diagram about master board and sensor

Comment: A circuit diagram. And at the very least link some datasheets. From your description it sounds like all you need is to put your signal through an inverting op amp with a gain of 1.

Comment: I know . Op amp useful for AC input, but my input is DC .

Comment: Op amps are also used for DC. It works the same way

Comment: i used to 
The Differential Amplifier . but output is incorrect .

Comment: So what you want is the inverse of your input? So if you have 9V in, you want -9V out? -5V in to get 5V out? If that is the case, a differential amplifier won't work. That just amplifies the difference between the 2 inputs. You need an inverting amplifier. Can you (again) update your question to include some sort of circuit diagram with your op amp circuit, and explain *clearly* what you want from this? I think I am starting to understand. Show power rails and everything in your circuit diagram

Comment: No, i dont try inverse the dc signal . I try to convert and change the scale . please see again last picture. I used to The Differential Amplifier. this circuit has 2 input . first input is dc signal from zero to nine and second signal is 4.5 VDC. (v2-v1). AFTER  Differential Amplifier i used to Non-inverting Operational Amplifier. but answer of circuit is incorrect.

Comment: I can't understand what you are wanting from that drawing. It is not a proper schematic so it means nothing to me. This really does need a schematic to be able to decipher. I've tried to understand but I cannot help any more without it. Even if English is not your first language, that is why engineers have schematics. That is something we *all* understand. You can use the schematic editor tool when editing your question

Comment: It's don't matter, I find good way, datasheet lm324 help me , datasheet useful rather than other way ,

Answer (score 4):

First thing you need to do is give yourself +9V and -9V rails. You can do this using a simple IC like the [LMC7660](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc7660.pdf).

If you use a comparator with these voltages on the supply rails, you can easily get your 0-9V signal to give you a +9V to -9V DC scale.

Comment: LMC7660 >> positive voltage in the range of +1.5V to +10V to
the corresponding negative voltage of −1.5V to −10V     BUT i need convert 0 until 9 VDC TO  -9 until +9

Comment: Yeah.... that IC will enable you to have a +9V rail and a -9V rail. Then use a comparator with those rails to turn your 0-9 into -9 To +9. Once you have the 2 rails, it's not that difficult

Comment: can you give me  schematic or circuit for this idea?

Comment: If I did that, you wouldn't learn anything. It should be extremely simple once you have the positive and negative rails. What you need to do is edit your question. Draw a schematic of what you have so far and explain why you need the +9 and -9 scale. Otherwise I could give you a circuit that is useless for your application. More information is definitely needed. Please do not attempt to explain in another comment. Edit your question and add a schematic and explanation.

Comment: i understand the rails     -----9volt-----R1----+----R2-----_9

Comment: Ok, so if you understand it, you should be able to use it. If not, then please do as I asked and edit your question for further clarity.

Comment: I should connect rail to which pin of that ic?

Comment: Read the datasheet which is linked. All the information for how to use the IC is in there

Comment: I read this data sheet one hours ago , excusme a lot , I don't understand for drawing circuit

Comment: If you are trying to design something, you **NEED** to be able to draw a schematic diagram. It is at the point where it is essential to see your current schematic along with a description of your intentions in order to help any more